# WHILE loop not working in a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I have multiple code blocks in a script where each block is executed based on the input parameter.

I created the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_Auto_Extraction_Parameterized] 
    @data nvarchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE (@data = '1')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM abc
    END;

    WHILE (@data = '2')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM xyz
    END;
    
    WHILE (@data = '3')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM def
    END 
END
```

The expected outcome after executing the stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC [usp_Auto_Extraction_Parameterized] @data = '3'
```

is that only the last code block should be executed, but here all the three blocks are executed.

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: What is the reason you are attempting to run a select query indefinitely in an infinite loop?

Comment: How is it indefinite?

Comment: Because the value of `@data` never changes; once you enter the loop you will *never* escape. Do you actually want `WHILE`? Perhaps you want `IF`?

Comment: So, should I replace WHILE with IF?

Comment: Presumably you can read the documentation for both keywords and likely answer that conundrum? `if` is a control-of-flow statement, `while` is a looping construct.

Comment: Maybe, depends what your actual goal is, but what you *claim* it's doing and what the code will do aren't the same.

Comment: @NaumanKhan, yes, you want `IF` based on your description. `WHILE` will repeat the code between BEGIN/END until the condition is false.

Comment: IF worked for what I wanted. Thanks all! @Stu, @ Thom, @ Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using IF-statements instead of WHILE. That should fix your problem:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_Auto_Extraction_Parameterized] @data nvarchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@data = '1')
  BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM abc
  END
  ELSE IF (@data = '2')
  BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM xyz
  END
  ELSE IF (@data = '3')
  BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM def
  END
END
```